# Material-UI Datagrid Pagination is starting on second page when given 1 for page

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, pagination

I'm using Material-UI Datagrid and I'm having an issue with the pagination. I have an api that will accept a page # and a limit like this page=${page}&limit=10`). Once the api is hit and returns 10 rows, I store those 10 rows along with any pagination data that Laravel is sending with paginate. It will look like this.

[image: Data Stored After API Call]

What is odd, is this is the right data for the first page but the pagination shows that it is the second page of data.

Here is what data the datagrid has from looking at the components tab in the console
[image: Datagrid State]

On initial load, this is what happens with the pagination

[image: Initial load of datagrid]

This is what the component looks like

[image: Component]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That component starts the count from 0. Make sure your `DataGrid` component is given 0 as `page` property value :)

Was probably made like that to ease your life when working with arrays.

I used [their demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4vtcw?file=/demo.js) and if you change the value in state to 0 it jumps to page 1.

Comment: Great. Material UI should document these ins and outs.

Comment: would be great if we could customize this -- starting at page = 0 can be confusing to some users